# Any suggestions to rotate array (multiframes) 90 in R

Tags: r, image

[I an trying to rotate a stack of images 417x600x30][1]

I used the following code but it did not work as shown in the picture below

```
lst = lapply(seq(dim(comb)[3]), function(x) comb[ , , x]) #convert to list

lst = lapply(lst, function(x) rot90(x, 1)) #rotate

#convert list back to array

re = array(as.numeric(unlist(lst)), dim=c(417, 600,3))
```

[enter image description here][2]

[enter image description here][3]

Comment: Dear Bilal, after the rotation what should the be the new dim? The same as the initial?

Comment: @AntreasI guess so

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work. You can specify which dimension you want to leave unrotated and it should probably also work for more than 3 dimensions.

```r
library(pracma)
library(abind)

# sample 2 x 3 x 4 array
x <- array(1:24, dim=c(2, 3, 4))
# dimension(s) to be kept (other two are rotated)
keep <- 1
# rotate slices of the array returning them as a list
rot <- lapply(asplit(x, keep), rot90, k=3)
# bind the slices into an array
rot <- do.call(abind, c(rot, along=length(dim(x))))
# reorder array dimensions
rot <- aperm(rot, order(c(seq_along(dim(x))[-keep], keep)))
```

A simple illustration of the rotation while keeping the first dimension intact:

```r
library(scatterplot3d)
par(mfrow=c(1, 2))
xyz <- do.call(expand.grid, lapply(dim(x), seq))
scatterplot3d(xyz, asp=1, color=0, bg=gray(x/24), pch=21, cex.symbols=2,
              x.ticklabs=NA, y.ticklabs=NA, z.ticklabs=NA)
xyz <- do.call(expand.grid, lapply(dim(rot), seq))
scatterplot3d(xyz, asp=1, color=0, bg=gray(rot/24), pch=21, cex.symbols=2,
              x.ticklabs=NA, y.ticklabs=NA, z.ticklabs=NA)
```

[image: Rotation illustration]

Comment: Thank you for this but 'rot <- do.call(abind, c(rot, along=length(dim(x)))) '# this gives me an error :second argument must be a list

Comment: rot <- aperm(rot, order(c(seq_along(dim(x))[-keep], keep))) # this give me the error: 'perm' is of wrong length 3 (!= 2)

Comment: Does it give you errors when you use the `x` array from my answer or your data?

Comment: ,I used my data

Comment: What does it look like? You mentioned an array in your question so my answer works with an array but if your data is in a different format it may cause problems. Can you share (at least a part of) it, e.g. using `dput`?

Comment: @Robertnum [1:417, 1:600, 1:30] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 3
  ..$ : NULL
  ..$ : NULL
  ..$ : NULL

Comment: This does look like an array. What does `str(rot)` return after you run `rot <- apply(x, keep, rot90, k=3, simplify=F)`? (if your data object is not named `x` then of course change `x` to what it is in your case)

Comment: @RobertI have this error 'simplify is unsed argument' when I remove it rot is  'int [1:1800, 1:417] 1 1 1 8 8 8 5 5 5 2 ...

Comment: Oh, I see, you are using an R version prior to 4.1.0 so there is no `simplify` argument for `apply`. I updated this line in my answer so that it does not rely on this functionality anymore so please go ahead and try it again with the updated code.

Comment: @Robertunfortunately, no. I will try to attach the outcome up

Comment: Here is the str(rot):int [1:417, 1:3, 1:600] 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 1 2 3 ...
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 3
  ..$ : NULL
  ..$ : NULL
  ..$ : NULL

Comment: Ok, two questions: 1. Does the code in my answer work as is now (not using your data)? And if it does, 2. if you replace the `x <- array(1:24, dim=c(2, 3, 4))` line with `x <- comb` does it still work? (I am assuming your data object is called `comb` but if it is not, change it for the name of your data object).

Comment: @RobertI did. may be related how I upload and concatenate data, here is my code: path = list.files("C:/Users/Bilal/Desktop/t",".jpg", full.names = T)
#?abind
im=lapply(path, readImage)
comb <- do.call(abind, c(im,list(along = 3)))

Comment: This looks fine and gives some more context but what are the answers to the two questions I asked in my previous comment?

Comment: @Robertyes, the code is working: int [1:2, 1:4, 1:3] 5 6 11 12 17 18 23 24 3 4 ...
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 3
  ..$ : NULL
  ..$ : NULL
  ..$ : NULL

Comment: @RobertI changed x<-comb but that gives me a black image with vertical grey line

Comment: Ok, we're getting closer! What happens if you change the value of `keep` from `1` to `3`?

Comment: Glad to hear that! No need for a coffee, it will be enough if you mark the answer as accepted. I am afraid I can't share any links on dealing with images as I don't work with such things, this was all about arrays for me.